# Where does my file go to when I upload it to multer on heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, multer

If I added multer upload to my app and set the upload directory to ./upload, and hosted it on heroku. when my app is up, where would the files go ? directly to the same ./upload? if so how do i get access to my files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t think Heroku is designed to host files (at least permanently). I would recommend [uploading them](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) to Amazon S3 instead (or any other file hosting provider).

See https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: is there any other option for uploading media files ?

Comment: Hi @Emyboy, Heroku doesn’t work like traditional servers. It’s designed to run amnesic (without storage) applications so we can’t upload files like we used to on traditional hosting or virtual or dedicated servers. You need to use a third party to upload user files such as profile pics which is more work but is great for scalability and portability as the assets are not on the same servers as the application.